# find current git branch while running job in pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, runner

how can I find out branch name in a job that is running in the pipeline?
I tried `git branch` all i get is 
 `* (detached from <commit number>)
  master`

Comment: This means you are not on a specific branch any more but on a specific commit with no branch pointing to it. What do you run before?

Comment: .gitlab-ci.yml script that runs in the pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a predefined variable called `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` that contains branch name. for more info [here](https://blue.cse.buffalo.edu/gitlab/help/ci/variables/README.md)

Comment: This is correct.Your can also use ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} if you want to escape some characters and get a kind of specific name based on the branch name. Check also ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} is you want to distinguish commits inside the same branch.